# Img to fit the div using css without stretching

Tags: html, css, image

I have an issue with css. I have to fit an image of variable size to a div with 100% width and 96vh. Also it should look good on resizing of the browser. I tried some tricks, but the result isn't good at all. Here is an example: http://dev.tourday.co/tour/Test-Emir-tour/45. The image looks really zoomed in on a 1366x768 resolution.

In this case I would like to get the result like when its completely zoomed out (something like this http://pokit.org/get/img/4445922ec2a29994b530d45759003d67.jpg).

I'm okay with the sides being cut out a bit because the aspect ratio of the picture is different than the div's, but I'd really like to avoid stretching.

Tried messing around with width:100%, and height:100%, but then stretching accours. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;`?

Comment: I did that as you can see in the link that I've sent, but still on high resolution it seems like the picture is very zoomed in.

Answer (score 1):

if you define the image as a background image for its container, you can use `background-size: cover` . This will cut off some parts (depending on the window proportions), but fill the whole container and not distort the image proportions. Adding `background-position: center`makes sure the middle part is always shown.

Comment: I tried this but I can only see a tiny portion of the picture if the pic is higher resolution. Check out my dev.tourday.co link up in OP, I want to accomplish what thats doing but when completely zoomed out.